# Closed curve not passing origin and winding number (complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, winding-number

I am pretty sure this is elementary, but I am having a hard time understanding winding number (although intuitively I think I get it). My reference is Brown & Churchill book, section 86 on argument principle.

My main concern is only about the independent of choice of starting point. Why is winding number independent of the choice of the starting point? Shouldn't it include modulo $2\pi$?

My understanding is that a closed curve $w(t)$ not passing the origin, say $0\leq t\leq 2$ (so that $w(0)=w(2)$), can be thought as a curve with parameter over any real $t$ such that $w(t)=w(t+2)$. This means that $w(1)=w(3)$, etc, does it not? If we fix an argument value for $arg(w(0))$ (since else it is multi-valued), I get why $A:=arg(w(2))-arg(w(0))$ is fixed. Similarly, I get why $B:=arg(w(3))-arg(w(1))$ is fixed, etc for any period $2$.

However, using equality of complex numbers in polar coordinates, I cannot deduce that $A=B$, but only $A=B+2\pi k$ for some $k$. In order to continue with the definition, I must make sure that $k=0$ always, right?

If I imagine some pictures, I surely understand the equality, but I cannot seem to convince myself about it rigorously. Maybe it has something to do with the continuity of the parameter?

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb C$ be a piecewise smooth, closed curve. Let $T\in[0,1]$ and $\gamma_1:=\gamma\vert_{[0,T]}$ and $\gamma_2:=\gamma\vert_{[T,1]}$. Basically just cut the curve into two parts at some arbitrary $T$. Now the curve with the original choice of starting point is $\gamma=\gamma_2\gamma_1$, where $\beta\alpha$ denotes the curve which first follows $\alpha$ and then $\beta$. With an arbitrary choice of $T$, we can now write the curve with a different choice of starting point as $\tilde\gamma=\gamma_1\gamma_2$. It's starting at $\gamma(T)$, the starting point of $\gamma_2$, and then follows the original curve from there.

Clearly, we have $\int_{\beta\alpha}f(z)\mathrm dz=\int_\alpha f(z)\mathrm dz+\int_\beta f(z)\mathrm dz$, and then we can just switch the order of summation however we want, so it doesn't matter wether we integrate over $\gamma_2\gamma_1$ or $\gamma_1\gamma_2$. This makes any integral over a closed curve independent of the choice of starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, what would be the connection between this and the arguments?

Comment: @10understanding: Winding number is $\operatorname{ind}(\gamma,z)=\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\mathrm dw$. It's better not to think too hard about the arguments, since the function $\operatorname{arg}$ can't tell you anything about how often you've gone around a pole. The argument of some number is always the same, no matter how you got to that number. You have $\operatorname{arg}(w(2))-\operatorname{arg}(w(0))=0$, which isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I eventually would indeed reach that winding number form, but the setup I am studying is from the Brown Churchill book, which does not start from that. In particular, I want to understand why the book confidently states "this argument change, of course, is independent of the choice of starting point". Moreover, I think from above I do not have $arg(w(2))-arg(w(0))=0$, because in the book, argument is multi-valued and we only fix a specific value of $arg(w(0))$. Hence, I suppose $arg(w(2))-arg(w(0))$ to be some number $A$ (which is of course a multiple of $2\pi$.